# Link with ID hash in URL changes the ID when opened in a new tab

Tags: angular, url, browser

Have one site that creates a link like `http://localhost:4300/?id=RTnySsxr8T2lPIihu2LqMw==&lang=en-us`

When that link is clicked a new browser tab opens at that URL.

But the hashed ID is changing in the address bar to `http://localhost:4300/?id=RTnySsxr8T2lPIihu2LqMw%3D%3D&lang=en-us`

I do *nothing* in between, in either app, it's just a link that opens a new tab.

I do get an error message "Padding is invalid and cannot be removed. id in url" from the server, but nothing is being transferred to the backend before the ID changes, that's  why (I assume) I get that 500 error, because the hashes don't match.

It's an Angular 13 app running on localhost:4200, the app that opens from the link is on 4300, and they both share a backend. Backend is C#.

So when I get the ID from the URL it's wrong.
What could be the cause of this?

Comment: It looks like the url is being encoded. `%3D` is `=`. I thought angular automatically decodes the url. How are you accessing the id param?

Comment: Yes i was getting the URL with `window.location`instead of `myURL = new URL(window.location.href)`and now I use that in `idParam = this.myURL.searchParams.get('id');`

Comment: You could also access via [`ActivatedRoute`](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute) like `id = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.queryParams.get(‘id’)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-example',
  templateUrl: './example.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./example.component.scss'],
})
export class ExampleComponent {
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    console.log(this.route.snapshot.queryParams['id']);
  }
}
```

Use this code because you want to get queryParams.